# How to clear Error in populating list view from mysql? [Info Updated]

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have solved a couple of errors but now I can't find the solve anymore. Does anyone now how to solve this error?
Error:

```
 Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
            at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
            at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
            at my.domain.app.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:62)
            at my.domain.app.Vergadertafel$LoadAllInfo.doInBackground(Vergadertafel.java:113)
            at my.domain.app.Vergadertafel$LoadAllInfo.doInBackground(Vergadertafel.java:91)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-05 11:11:04.256    1478-1494/my.domain.app E/Buffer Error﹕ Error converting result
    java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
            at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:64)
            at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:79)
            at my.domain.app.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:77)
            at my.domain.app.Vergadertafel$LoadAllInfo.doInBackground(Vergadertafel.java:113)
            at my.domain.app.Vergadertafel$LoadAllInfo.doInBackground(Vergadertafel.java:91)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-05 11:11:04.286    1478-1494/my.domain.app E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data
    org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
            at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
            at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
            at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:155)
            at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
            at my.domain.app.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:92)
            at my.domain.app.Vergadertafel$LoadAllInfo.doInBackground(Vergadertafel.java:113)
            at my.domain.app.Vergadertafel$LoadAllInfo.doInBackground(Vergadertafel.java:91)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)

            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-05 11:11:04.326    1478-1494/my.domain.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: my.domain.app, PID: 1478
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at my.domain.app.Vergadertafel$LoadAllInfo.doInBackground(Vergadertafel.java:116)
            at my.domain.app.Vergadertafel$LoadAllInfo.doInBackground(Vergadertafel.java:91)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Vergadertafel.java:

```
package my.domain.app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Vergadertafel extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> infoList;

    // url to get all info list
    private static String de_info = "http://127.0.0.1/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_INFO = "info";

    // info JSONArray
    JSONArray info = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vergadertafel);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        infoList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading info in Background Thread
        new LoadAllInfo().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single info
        // launching Edit Info Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Info.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }


    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all info by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllInfo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Vergadertafel.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Even geduld alstublieft...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All info from url
         a* */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(de_info, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Info: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success== 0) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ik kan momenteel niet met de database communiceren, controleer uw internet verbinding en probeer het later nog eens.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } else if (success == 1) {
                // info found
                // Getting Array of Info
                info = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Info
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = info.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_INFO);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_INFO, name);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    infoList.add(map);
                }

            } else {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Er is momenteel geen informatie beschikbaar, probeert u het later nog eens.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSONException rule", " 153 Error:", e);
        }

        return null;
    }


        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all info
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            Vergadertafel.this, infoList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                            TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Info.java:

```
package my.domain.app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Info extends Activity {

    TextView textView;

    String pid;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // single product url
    private static final String url_product_details = "http://127.0.0.1/android_connect/get_product_details.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_INFO = "info";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.info);


    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
     * */
    class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Info.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Info aan het laden. Even Geduld...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_product_details, "GET", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_NAME); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            // product with this pid found
                            // Edit Text
                            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

                            // display product data in TextView
                            textView.setText(product.getString(TAG_INFO));

                        }else{
                            // product with pid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }


        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to  Save product Details
     * */

    }
```

JSONParser.java:

```
package my.domain.app;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if("POST".equals(method)){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if("GET".equals(method)){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("UnsupportedEncodingException", "error message:", e);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e("ClientProtocolException", "error message", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IOException", "error message", e);
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result ", e);
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data ", e);
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Vergadertafel.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/pallasrood"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/android"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1">

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Product id (pid) - will be HIDDEN - used to pass to other activity -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />


    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The info is updated!
[Link from tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Comment: This is a lot of code to look through. Have a look at "[*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" for some tips on making your question better - as it stands, it's hard to help you with the quantity of code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first exception

> Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null

comes from the fact that `is` is null in this line:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
```

It can be `null` if `if(method == "GET")` was `false` or due to exception in this block. If no other exceptions were raised prior that NPE, then I would recommend you to change `method == "GET"` to `"GET".equals(method)`. I know that Java interns all String literals, but some JVM versions can garbage-collect such interned strings, so this may be the case in Android. And it's better never to use `==` on strings and always check equality of strings by their `equals` method.

P.S. Change all `e.printStackTrace()` to `Log.e("some tag", "error message", e)` and lines like this `Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString())` to `Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data ", e)` for better exceptions logging.

Comment: I have applied your instuctions and have updated te question with refreshed errors and script.

Comment: So you are trying to make a request from Android app to some web server. And I suppose you have that web server running on your local computer. But the URL in your code is wrong - 127.0.0.1 is just an IP address that points to itself. So if you try to connect to 127.0.0.1 from Android phone or emulator it will simply try to connect to itself (to phone or emulator). In your case you need to change IP address in the URL to IP address of your computer where web server is running.

Comment: Okay I understand, but he closed the app and I want that he does  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ik kan momenteel niet met de database communiceren, controleer uw internet verbinding en probeer het later nog eens." of the Vergadertafel.java

Comment: You show that message only if server returns json with success field != 1. But if a server is not responding or you don't have Internet connection then  your application will fail earlier. You can see from the stacktrace of the first exception that your application fails on line 62 of JSONParser. Then this exception is caught by your catch blocks. But after that you are still trying to parse a result from a server. In particular you are trying to work with variable "is", which is null. And of course application fails again with "lock == null" NPE exception.

Comment: You need to change the way you handle exceptions in your code. The simplest solution for you would be checking if result of **makeHttpRequest** method is null, and if so - show toast with message about problems with connections. So if it returns **null** then the request was not successful.

Comment: I have edited the code in Vergadertafel.java with an ordder for succes=0 but he does close the app. I think I should change anything in de JSONParser.java but I don't know what.

Comment: Okay. Just after the line `JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(de_info, "GET", params)` put `if (json == null)` block. And put the message about no Internet connection inside of this block. The last line of this block must be `return null`. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

i think the error is, your trying to display a toast message in your loadAll info asynctask class...

you need runuithread to display toast in a backgroud process....

and in your getproductdetails class, your also trying to make UI change from a backgroud process...

in this line..

```
  textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

                        // display product data in TextView
                        textView.setText(product.getString(TAG_INFO));
```

try to run this also in runuithread...

Comment: The changes hadn't effect.

Comment: can u post the JSON data?